# Indeterminate solution of 2nd order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, series-expansion, nonlinear

I seek to prove a solution in power series in `y` or by numerical methods for the second order nonlinear differential equation:

```
nlde = {Sqrt[1 - f[y]^2] f''[y] + y == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 1};
```

It seems that there is an analytical answer in power series for this ODE (see [appendix in this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/0001-6160(73)90105-3)):

[image]

My failed attempts to prove the analytical solution with Mathematica:

Power series:

```
AsymptoticDSolveValue[nlde, f, {y, 0, 4}]
(* Indeterminate expression 0 ComplexInfinity encountered*)
```

```
Series[DifferentialRoot[Function @@ {{f, y}, nlde}][y], {y, 0, 4}]
(* supplied equation is not a
linear differential equation with polynomial coefficient *)
```

Numerical:

```
NDSolveValue[nlde, f, {y, 0, 4}]
(* Infinite expression encountered*)
```

Anyone has any suggestions on how to solve the equation? Thanks!

Comment: The ode is singular for `t=0`!

Comment: If you look at the result of `SolveAlways[With[{f = C[0] + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 1, 6}] + O[y]^7}, Sqrt[1 - f^2] D[f, {y, 2}] + y == 0], y]`, you might get an idea on what constraints your series coefficients have to follow for a power series to satisfy your nonlinear ODE.

Comment: Yes, it is singular. Somehow there appears to be an analytic solution in power series (see edited question). The approach of using SolveAlways doesn't seem to give the same coefficients as the expected results

Comment: Using the excerpt you have shown, you could use `SolveAlways[]` with formula A6: `1 + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 2, 10}] /. With[{g = -Sum[C[k] y^(k - 2), {k, 2, 10}] + O[y]^(11 - 2)}, Last[SolveAlways[g (2 - y^2 g) (y^2 D[g, {y, 2}] + 4 y D[g, y] + 2 g)^2 == 1, y]]]`

Comment: Yes, your approach is correct. It seems that  ```SolveAlways``` is picking even the other solutions for the imaginary coefficients!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we rationalize the DE, we can get an asymptotic solution:

```
nlde2 = {(1 - f[y]^2) f''[y]^2 - y^2 == 0, f'[0] == 0, f[0] == 1};
asol = AsymptoticDSolveValue[nlde2, f, {y, 0, 8}]
```

> AsymptoticDSolveValue::asdb: There are multiple solution branches for the equations, but AsymptoticDSolveValue will return only one.
>
> ```
> 1 - y^2/2 - y^4/104 - (67 y^6)/83824 - (49463 y^8)/496908672
> ```

It returns a solution that satisfies the original `nlde` for `y >= 0`:

```
sol = {f -> Function[y, Evaluate[asol + O[y]^(Exponent[asol, y] + 1)]]}
```

> [image]

```
First@nlde /. Equal -> Subtract /. sol
Simplify[%, y >= 0]
```

> [image]

#### Alternative

Implementing the method in the paper (sans rationalization):

```
nlde3 = nlde /. f -> Function[y, 1 - y^2 g[y]] // 
  FullSimplify[#, y > 0] &
```

> [image]

```
1 - y^2 AsymptoticDSolveValue[{First@nlde3, Reduce[nlde3 /. y -> 0]}, 
    g, {y, 0, 6}] // Expand
```

> [image]

Comment: I think the point is that `Sqrt[]` is not analytic at `0`, which is where `Sqrt[1 - f[y]^2]` starts.

Comment: Thanks! It seems the trick is to rationalise the ODE with the square root term. The power series solution works now. The numerical approach with ```NDSolveValue[nlde2, f, {y, 0, 4}]``` still complains about indeterminate expressions encountered.

Answer (score 1):

A direct way to get the solution, known from perturbation theory, follows with assumptions `f=1+y+...`and `y>0`

```
cl = CoefficientList[Simplify[Normal[Series[Sqrt[1 - f[y]^2] f''[y] + y 
/.f -> Function[y, 1 + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 2, 6}]], {y, 0, 5}]],y > 0], y]

sol=Solve[0 == cl , {C[2], C[3], C[4], C[5], C[6]}]
(*{{C[2] -> -(1/2), C[3] -> 0, C[4] -> -(1/104), C[5] -> 0,C[6] -> -(67/83824)}}*)

Function[y, 1 + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 2, 6}]][y]/.sol
(*1 - y^2/2 - y^4/104 - (67 y^6)/83824*)
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach works. It seems to be critical to set the two first terms ```1+0``` and then add the coefficients for this work.

Comment: @Ferca The method works for the general case `C[0],C[1]` too. Analyzing the coefficientlist let you derive conditions for the existence of a power serie.

Comment: ```cl = CoefficientList[
   Simplify[
    Normal[Series[
      Sqrt[1 - f[y]^2] f''[y] + y /. 
       f -> Function[y, C[0] + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 1, 6}]], {y, 0, 5}]],
     y > 0], y];
sol = Solve[0 == cl, {C[0], C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4], C[5], C[6]}];
Function[y, C[0] + Sum[C[k] y^k, {k, 1, 6}]][y] /. sol;
% /. C[0] -> 1```  leads to ```Indeterminate```

Comment: @Ferca No , you have to solve it step by step: First look at  `cl[[1]]` which vanishs for `C[0]->1 (or C[2]->0)` , Second set `C[0]=1` and look at `cl[[1]]` which only vanishs for `C[1]->1`. And so on...

Comment: @Ferca In this way you might find a second solution for arbitrary `C[0],C[1]` : `Solve[0 == cl[[1 ;; 3]], {C[2], C[3], C[4]}] // Simplify (*{{C[2] -> 0, C[3] -> -(1/(6 Sqrt[1 - C[0]^2])), 
  C[4] -> -((C[0] C[1])/(12 (1 - C[0]^2)^(3/2)))}}*)`

Comment: Your answer is correct. ```cl[[1]] == 0 // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {x_ \[Element] Reals}] &
Solve[%, {C[0], C[2]}]
cl[[2]] == 0 // Simplify[#, Assumptions -> {x_ \[Element] Reals}] &
Solve[%, {C[1]}] /. {C[0] -> 1}``` gives  the 1 and 0. Key was to solve for ```C[1]```  from ```cl[[2]]==0``` before substituting the ```C[0]->1```.

Comment: I like your approach

Comment: @Ferca Thanks, perhaps the second solution with free `C[0],C[1]` finds your interest too?

Comment: yes, indeed. It helps to understand what's behind the scenes with ```AsymptoticDSolveValue```